# OAuth server API (Freesound) succeeds in cURL but fails in Java

Tags: java, http, curl, post, oauth-2.0

I'd like to access the Freesound API via Java for Clojure (in the context of the [Overtone](http://overtone.github.io/) project).

The cURL request, taken from the documentation here:
https://freesound.org/docs/api/authentication.html#oauth2-authentication
is:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code&code=THE_GIVEN_CODE" https://freesound.org/apiv2/oauth2/access_token/
```

I narrowed it down to this program failing in Java with an HTTP 405, even though the equivalent succeeds in cURL. What is going wrong?

Also, note that the Overtone code to post the request used to work, but it seems to have stopped at some point. It is here:
https://github.com/overtone/overtone/blob/master/src/overtone/samples/freesound.clj#L79

```
class req {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String client_id = "CLIENT_ID";
        String api_key = "API_KEY";
        String code = "CODE";
        String url = "https://www.freesound.org/apiv2/oauth2/access_token/";
        String query = "client_id="+client_id+"&api_key="+api_key+"&grant_type=authorization_code&code="+code;
        print_input(post_request(url, query));
    }
    static java.io.InputStream post_request(String url_text, String query) throws Exception {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(url_text);
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection con = (javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection)(url.openConnection());
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        //con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        //con.connect();
        java.io.BufferedWriter w = new java.io.BufferedWriter(new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream()));
        w.write(query);
        print_headers(con);
        return con.getInputStream();
    }
    static void print_headers(java.net.URLConnection con) {
        java.util.Map<String, java.util.List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, java.util.List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": "+ entry.getValue());
    }
    }
    static void print_input(java.io.InputStream input) throws Exception {
        java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(input));
        String line = null;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
% javac req.java
% java req      
allow: [POST, OPTIONS]
date: [Sat, 05 Mar 2022 04:03:47 GMT]
null: [HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed]
content-length: [0]
server: [istio-envoy]
Strict-Transport-Security: [max-age=31536000; preload]
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: [8]
vary: [Cookie]
x-frame-options: [SAMEORIGIN]
content-type: [text/html; charset=utf-8]
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: https://freesound.org/apiv2/oauth2/access_token/
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2035)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2030)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:2029)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1597)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at req.post_request(req.java:22)
    at req.main(req.java:10)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: https://freesound.org/apiv2/oauth2/access_token/
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1985)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFields(HttpURLConnection.java:3229)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderFields(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:253)
    at req.print_headers(req.java:25)
    at req.post_request(req.java:21)
    ... 1 more
```

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. It has nothing to do with Java. It turns out to be a 405, because we're using [www.freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org) instead of freesound.org!

The lesson is that a 405 is about wrong method (POST vs GET) or wrong URL (HTTPS vs HTTP, plain vs www). What was insidious is that the header still indicated that POST was allowed and yet it failed.